# Simple http request on WP8 on obscured

Tags: c#, http, windows-phone-8

So basically I made it so my app runs in the background if the phone is locked using this

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

Then I created an event so when the application is obscured(the phone is locked) it would run doing the following.

```
PhoneApplicationFrame phoneAppRootFrame = RootFrame;
App.RootFrame.Obscured += RootFrame_Obscured;
```

Now here is my request code.. there has to be something wrong with it, though I'm not sure what anymore. I've been trying so many different ways of just doing a simple get request, I don't even need to parse any response. It just never seems to work, anyways here it is:

```
private void RootFrame_Obscured(object sender, ObscuredEventArgs e)
{
  string url = "http://localhost:8080/someserver/javaQuery?request=storeId&id=someId";
  HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
  webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(httpComplete), webRequest);
}

private static void httpComplete(IAsyncResult asyncResult){

}
```

I'm completely positive that the RootFrame_Obscured function is running, but the request code itself is probably wrong. Any insight would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to perform network calls under the lock screen.

[Checklist for apps that disable app idle detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> If your Windows Phone app disables app idle detection to run under the
>   lock screen, **you should perform the following tasks** to reduce your
>   app’s power consumption while the lock screen is engaged.
>
> - Signal your app that new network
>     requests and isolated storage operations shouldn’t be performed.

If you need to track this event you can do that in [`Unobscured`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.unobscured%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)  event handler.